# typescript типы для api 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть ли возможность использовать typescript типы для api 3.0 карт? Судя по всему исходники написаны на typescript. Может я плохо читал доку и где то на  DefinitelyTyped уже есть пакет с типами?

Comment: Ну, первая ссылка из гугла, наверное? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/yandex-maps → https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/yandex-maps

Comment: Это для v2 типы от сторонних разрабов. Обновил вопрос, имелись ввиду типы для 3.0

Comment: Возможно это? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yandex/ymaps3-types (работоспособность не проверял, просто вдумчиво нагуглил)

Comment: О, вот это уже похоже на правду. Написано "Types are automatically generated based on source files". Спасибо! Странно что в документацию не добавили инфу об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется в их документации есть ссылка на пакет:

https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/dg/concepts/typescript

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)